# Change app language on click of UIButton action Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

My app is in two languages. (English & Arabic)

Now my app is working well on both language but its depends on device language.
Having two files with `Localizable.strings`

I want to make this device language independent.

I have one UIButton which will open popup with language name along with two respective radio buttons.
Select radio button and click OK.

On clicking the OK button I need to change the language of app from English to Arabic and vice versa

I search a lot and found some limited info, handling the change in main file.

Can any one guide me for the same.
Also I need to Flush all the data of the app on change of language.
(`NSUserDefaults` data to be flush)

Comment: Please post some code of what you tried instead of posting your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the language of your app you need to use localisation concept. Also you need to change the UI of your app as per arabic language as in arabic their is right alignment for data. you can store the selected language in user defaults

when  you select the language store it as
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YOUR_SELETED_LANGUAGE" forKey:@"SelectedLanguage"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

& check the condition for setting the alinement.

```
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SelectedLanguage"]isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SELETED_LANGUAGE"])
{
     YOUR_LABLE.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
}
else
{
     YOUR_LABLE.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
}
```

In this way, by checking selected language you need to change UI of your app. This is what I did in my app.

Comment: you can refer the above link for localization

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change every localized string of your app when the user click on a single button, you can use the following code :

```
// for example: language = @"en"  and region = @"UK"
NSString* languageDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",language,region]
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: languageDescription, nil] 
                                                                   forKey: @"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //to make the change immediate
```

This should change the language used in your entire app.

If you want to persist this language, and use it by default each time the application is launched, you'll have to store the 'languageDescription' (in the NSUserDefault for example), and run the code above each time the app is launched (in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method)